# Hide dropdownButton in shiny dashboardHeaderPlus

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a `shinydashboardPlus` with two `dropdownButton`s in the header. Each button corresponds with a tab, and I would like to hide the button whose tab is not selected. I have provided a minimal working example below. Thank you in advance!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPagePlus(
    dashboardHeaderPlus(
      left_menu = tagList(
        dropdownButton(
          inputId = "select_company_button",
          label = "Select Company",
          icon = icon("store"),
          circle = FALSE,
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = "select_company",
            label = "Company",
            multiple = TRUE,
            choices = c("ALL Companies" = ""),
            selected = NULL,
            options = list(
              closeAfterSelect = TRUE, 
              plugins = list("remove_button")))
        ),
        dropdownButton(
          inputId = "select_industry_button",
          label = "Select Industry",
          icon = icon("industry"),
          circle = FALSE,
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = "select_industry",
            label = "Industry",
            multiple = TRUE,
            choices = c("ALL Industries" = ""),
            selected = NULL,
            options = list(
              closeAfterSelect = TRUE, 
              plugins = list("remove_button")))
        )
      )
    ),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "tabs",
        menuItem(
          text = "Company", 
          tabName = "company",
          icon = icon("store")
        ),
        menuItem(
          text = "Industry", 
          tabName = "industry",
          icon = icon("industry")
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem("company"),
        tabItem("industry")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({ 
    
    if(input$tabs == "company") {
      #show company dropdown button
      #hide industry dropdown button
    } else{
      #hide company dropdown button
      #show industry dropdown button
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `renderUI` should do it.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPagePlus(
    dashboardHeaderPlus(
      left_menu = tagList(
        uiOutput("tab1")
      )
    ),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        id = "tabs",
        menuItem(
          text = "Company", 
          tabName = "company",
          icon = icon("store")
        ),
        menuItem(
          text = "Industry", 
          tabName = "industry",
          icon = icon("industry")
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem("company"),
        tabItem("industry")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$tab1 <- renderUI({
    if(input$tabs == "company") {
      dropdownButton(
        inputId = "select_company_button",
        label = "Select Company",
        icon = icon("store"),
        tabName = "company",
        circle = FALSE,
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = "select_company",
          label = "Company",
          multiple = TRUE,
          choices = c("ALL Companies" = ""),
          selected = NULL,
          options = list(
            closeAfterSelect = TRUE, 
            plugins = list("remove_button")))
      )
      #show company dropdown button
      #hide industry dropdown button
    } else{
      dropdownButton(
        inputId = "select_industry_button",
        label = "Select Industry",
        icon = icon("industry"),
        circle = FALSE,
        selectizeInput(
          inputId = "select_industry",
          label = "Industry",
          multiple = TRUE,
          choices = c("ALL Industries" = ""),
          selected = NULL,
          options = list(
            closeAfterSelect = TRUE, 
            plugins = list("remove_button")))
      )
      #hide company dropdown button
      #show industry dropdown button
    }
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using renderUI every time the user switches tabs? I would still like the selectizeInputs to exist so I can access their values, but I would like them to be hidden to the user. In my real app, I have four tabs and selectizeInput, so just hiding them via javascript would be great.

Comment: I am not that familiar with javascript.  User input can be done using selectizeInput on the server side.